# XBox GPU Does not appear in C++ AMP accelerator list

Tags: c++, xbox, c++-amp, xbox-one

I'm using C++ AMP on XBox, but when I try to select the GPU as the default accelerator, it does not come up in the list. This is the code I'm using for finding the available accelerators:

```
std::vector<accelerator> accs = accelerator::get_all();
// Use all accelerators but the CPU
for (int i = 0; i < accs.size(); i++)
{
    std::wcout << "Using accelerator " << i + 1 << " of " << accs.size() << " - "
        << accs[i].description << " @ " << accs[i].device_path << "\n";
}
```

I'm only getting `Microsoft Basic Render Driver` and `CPU Accelerator`. Both run my code ~5 times slower than what I get on the PC.

Why doesn't the GPU appear in the accelerator list? Is it disabled somehow?

Comment: Does the XBox GPU support DX11/C++AMP? The drivers you list would be expected to be slow as they are emulators.

Comment: I came here because I searched on Google whether the Xbox One supports this. Can I conclude "no"?

Comment: Probably, unless they added support in the last couple of months